# How to remove a letter initial from a name in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

I have a dataframe contains a name column with this format (last name, first name initial) like below. The initial will be always at the last and has one letter only.

How to remove the initial? I know re may be able to handle this task but I am not sure how the pattern would look like. Any advice would be great.

```
import pandas as pd
d={'name':['Smith, John', 'Smith, Johnson W', 'Smith, Joan D', 'Smith, Joan X', 'Smith, Brian Borbinson] }
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Comment: Looks like you could iterate over each element, split spaces and only take 0th and 1st item in that split array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import re

d={'name':['Smith, John', 'Smith, Johnson W',
           'Smith, Joan D', 'Smith, Joan X', 'Smith, Brian Borbinson'] }
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)


def remove_second_name_initial(string):
    string_copy = string
    string_surname = string.split(', ')[0]
    string_name = string.split(', ')[1]
    string_first_name = string_name.split(' ')[0]
    try:
        string_second_name = string_name.split(' ')[1]
    except:
        # In case that there is not initial or second name
        return string_surname + ', ' + string_name
    if len(string_second_name) == 1:
        # Just removing the intial
        return string_surname+', '+string_first_name
    # this give back the whole name, this is to leave the complete second name
    # as in Smith, Brian Borbinson
    return string_surname+', '+string_name

df.apply(lambda x:remove_second_name_initial(x['name']) ,axis = 1)
0               Smith, John
1            Smith, Johnson
2               Smith, Joan
3               Smith, Joan
4    Smith, Brian Borbinson
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank Rafael for the thorough explanation. This’s very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to test if the string ends with an initial, then remove the last two characters of the string if so. You could use this pattern for that test.

```
\s[a-zA-Z]$
```

`\s` tests for a single space
`[a-zA-Z]` tests for a single letter and allows for a lowercase letter - use `[A-Z]` if you only want capitals
`$` asserts the end of the line

This, of course, would fail if someone's name was *Smith, J D*, though that case would likely be *Smith, J.D.* or *Smith, JD*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detail explanation. Since I want to remove the initial from the whole column, can I do something like this? re.sub('\s[A-Z]$','',df['name']) But this seems not working

Comment: I'm rusty on pandas, but I think you'd need to use .apply() with your code as a lambda function for its argument

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.